# HIVE - Omitting exact bracketed substring from a string field

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a string field with records like the following

“Harry Potter (HP) (ab-cd)”
“John Doe (ab-cd)”
“Richard Smith (RS)”
“William Johnson”

I would like to remove the “(ab-cd)” part from all records without removing any other bracketed expressions.

The results should be:
“Harry Potter (HP)”
“John Doe”
“Richard Smith (RS)”
“William Johnson”

I think regexp_replace() needs to be used; but I am not good with regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

use simple `replace()` if you are not replacing a pattern. You dont have to use slow & complex regex.

```
select replace('Harry Potter (HP) (ab-cd)','(ab-cd)','')
```

[image]